# Partial derivative of function of several variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How come $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}) = \frac{x V`(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$.

I don't understand why did we get this term V` over in the expression as well. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we are to take the partial derivative with respect to the first argument of the map $(x,y,z) \overset{f}{\mapsto} \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}} =: u \overset{V}{\mapsto} V(u),$
so by chain rule we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(V \circ f)(x,y,z) = D_{1}(V \circ f)(x,y,z) = V'(u)\cdot D_{1}f(x,y,z) = V'(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}})\cdot \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}} = \frac{xV'(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}.
$$

Comment: Is V` here is derivative of V with respect to time ?

Comment: No. its w.r.t $x$.

Comment: @Illustionist: Note that $V$ eats only one real input, so no partial derivative of $V$ takes place; the bottom line here is the composition of maps and chain rule. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since V is a composition of the function  $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. Hence, differentiating $V(\cdot)$ w.r.t $x$, yields $V'$ in the differentiation. E.g. try diff. $\log (\sqrt(x))$ w.r.t $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is about partial derivative w.r.t $x$ and $V$ is a function of $x$, $y$ and $z$, so we consider $y$ and $z$ as constants and then find the derivative of $V$ w.r.t $x$. So $V'$ denote the derivative of $V$ and since the term inside the bracket is not $x$ so we differentiate it w.r.t. $x$, there by coming at the given expression.

Note: $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$